# Timeouts are not supported on this stream

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

Could someone explain why i am getting **Timeouts are not supported on this stream.** error.

If i use my code like this everythings fine. My sockets connects to server adn retreives info. (This method was like dummy cause the connection was happening for one server and at the start of everything)

```
 private async Task Update()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            server = Ips.First();
            if (server.Map != sq.map || server.Name != sq.name || server.Players != sq.players)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
   }
```

While in real app i need to query a lot of servers. So i try something like this ( cause i'm noob and cant figure out a better way )

```
foreach (var server in Ips)
            {
                sq.Connect(new Windows.Networking.HostName(server.Ip), server.Port);

                if (server.Map != sq.map || server.Name != sq.name || server.Players != sq.players)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
```

And that's where i get **Timeouts are not supported on this stream error.** Can someone explain why and maybe tell me where should i look in too?

My error comes in first line of this method:
**(Stream streamIn = args.GetDataStream().AsStreamForRead();)**

```
        private async void Socket_MessageReceived(DatagramSocket sender, DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
    {

        Stream streamIn = args.GetDataStream().AsStreamForRead();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamIn);
        string message = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        byte[] packet = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        Parser parser = new Parser(packet);
```

Comment: Do remember that data received from the Internet must be processed or saved by the app IMMEDIATELY or it will be lost (it's urgent I/O). That's what the error says.

Comment: But why does the first method work?

Comment: Because timeouts are caused by doing many things at once, and doing just one thing or two won't mean the same amount of load. With 1 or 2 things it's got time to handle all. With more, it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why does the first method work?

The main difference between your first code block and the second one is `sq.Connect(new Windows.Networking.HostName(server.Ip), server.Port);`, base on your code, it is possible that

- you only connect to `Ips.First()`, and the code run to "return" to jump out of the "foreach".
- you establish two(or more) connections until the code run to "return".

I don't know what is your `sq`, and there is no `Connect(hostname, serverport)` method in [DatagramSocket class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.datagramsocket.aspx), there is only a similar method but an aysnc one: [DatagramSocket.ConnectAsync(HostName, String) | connectAsync(HostName, String) method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241353.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Mapping to the two possibilities I listed up:

- if the code in "foreach" only run one time (means `Ips.First()` connected), then the difference between two code block is you established a connection in the second code, this could be a reason.
- for the second possibility, I assume that you are using `ConnectAsync` method actually, then `sq` is `c sq = new DatagramSocket();`, and it is connected to several servers using one `DatagramSocket`. But `ConnectAsync` method is for communicate with a single remote endpoint, so I think it could also be the reason here.

> While in real app i need to query a lot of servers.

I think for your scenario, **it's better not using connections**, you can bind your `DatagramSocket` to a local port, and join a `DatagramSocket` object to a multicast group. You can refer to the official [DatagramSocket sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DatagramSocket), the scenario 5 is for multicast and broadcast, you can take a look.

If you have any problems here, please leave a comment.

Comment: sq is ServerQuery() it contains datagramsocket and connectasync. I fixed it kinda. Just did try{} everything and ignored exceptions so probably it was happening like this because app was still loading? (maybe?) And the real goal is user can add his own Server to observable collection ( i mean Ip/port) and app will query them for data. So should i use multicast for this?

Comment: @Myrez, yes, I think so, using multicast is better.

Comment: Well thank you! I manager to make it work. Anyways you would see this bodge i made :D You would laugh for a week.